# Comparing array_sum(string) to an integer in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I came across this line of code while examining the `convertFromJSCharcode` function in [PHPIDS/Monitor](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/70174413/).

```
foreach ($charcode as $char) {
            $char = preg_replace('/\W0/s', '', $char);

            if (preg_match_all('/\d*[+-\/\* ]\d+/', $char, $matches)) {
                $match = preg_split('/(\W?\d+)/', implode('', $matches[0]), null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

                if (array_sum($match) >= 20 && array_sum($match) <= 127) {
                    $converted .= chr(array_sum($match));
                }

            } elseif (!empty($char) && $char >= 20 && $char <= 127) {
                $converted .= chr($char);
            }
        }
```

How can I compare `array_sum($match)` to an integer? My understanding is that `array_sum($match)` is a string. The same goes for `$cha`r.

Comment: Do: `var_dump($match);` and you see what type it has.

Comment: As per my understanding array_sum returns value in integer or float by the way what are you getting in $match ? if you have an string you may cast it and convert into integer something like (int)$match & then compare.

Comment: what is the data in your $charcode?

Answer (score 1):

From this [document](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php), array_sum will return a number (that is integer or float).

Answer (score 1):

Check the [`array_sum`](https://devdocs.io/php/function.array-sum) documentation:

> `array_sum()` returns the sum of values in an array.
>
> [...]
>
> #### Return Values
>
> **Returns the sum of values as an integer or float.**

Answer (score 1):

As per my [understanding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) `array_sum` returns value in

> **integer or float**

if you have an string you may cast it and convert into integer something like `(int)$match` & then compare.